# Anyone know how to connect c++dll with vb6?

Tags: c++, vb6

Currently i was being asked to connect the c++ dll with vb 6 and i was being provided a line of sample code on how to use it and below is the sample code
`Public Declare Function ABC_ConnectDevice Lib "ABC_API.dll" (ByVal strCommPort As String, ByVal lngBaudRate As Long, ByRef RespData As sRespData) As Long`

and this is the code i currently write and require to connect with

```
ABC_API_API long __stdcall ABC_ConnectDevice(long dwPort, long dwSpeed)
{
    long lngResult, lngRtn;
    char strMsg[512];
    memset((void*)strMsg, '\0', sizeof(strMsg));
    READERHANDLE ptrCardDispenser;

    try {
        lngResult = F3_Connect(dwPort, dwSpeed, NULL, &ptrCardDispenser);
        if(lngResult == 0) {
            g_Reader = &ptrCardDispenser;
            lngRtn = 0;
            

        } else {
            lngRtn = -1;
            
        }

        return lngRtn;
    } catch (exception& e) {
        sprintf_s(strMsg, "Exception@ReadIni: %s", e.what());
        WriteError(strMsg);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

as you can see, the parameter inside the c++ is long dwport, and long swSpeed, so when vb6 part, i add in that 2 parameter but when i run it, what i get is compile error, arguement not optional.
below would be the code which i use in the form and module

```
Private Sub btnOpenConnection_Click()

Dim openComm As Long
openComm = MTK_ConnectDevice()
MsgBox openComm

End Sub
```

and below is the code i write in module

```
Public Declare Function ABC_ConnectDevice Lib "ABC_API.dll" (ByVal lngdwPort, ByVal lngdwSpeed) As Long
```

i currently assume that i might pass in the wrong parameter but the parameter which i used in c++ indeed is dwPort and dwSpeed only.. so i really got abit clueless on did i require to pass in extra parameter or anypart is doing wrong

this is the 3rd day i actually use c++ and vb6 so dont be so harsh to me and i just want to know what is the issue on the code only and how should i fix it.It can be refer to what kind of document or sample code.Thank you.

**Hi, the question had been solved after refering to the manufacture document which mentioned what data value i should pass in. Appreciate everyone who trying to help me solved together and teaching me.As a beginner for c++, i would really appreciate this community which is beginner friendly and willing to teach me step by step even though we didn't know each others in real life.Thank you for all the people who helping me to solved the issue.Thank you once again**

Comment: Your function need two parameters, why don't you add them? Is it because you don't know what they should be?

Comment: yes, i really dont know what are they should be, due i really had to admit i got not much knowledge about it and this is really my 3rd day using c++ and vb6, i had tried like google for pass 6 hours for just how to use dll for vb6 but after viewing those google result, i still no clue on how to fix this actually

Comment: But then this isn't a question about C++ and VB6 at all, it's about this third party API that you are using (`F3_Connect`). That's a completely different question. You know how to pass the parameters but you just don't know what they should be. I can't help you but maybe [this link](https://www.lintechtt.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/F3-APIDLL-instructions.pdf) will.

Comment: appreciate your link sir. but as the link u sent mentioned, the parameter name was DWORD dwPort ,DWORD dwSpeed and this would be the things i need to pass in, so is that correct is i put the parameter like this would be correct? Function MTK_ConnectDevice Lib "MTKF32X3_API.dll" (ByVal dwPort as long, ByVal dwSpeed as long) As Long, due i do had to admit i got abit not understand with the link u sent to me ,in the document, it mention it needed the Dword dwPort and dwSpeed as input so when i pass in the data, i need change both of them as long and put in the public declare and it should be ok?

Comment: but no matter how, thank you for showing the place which i can refer to and fix my issue... really appreciate your help.

Comment: [This](https://www.codingdomain.com/visualbasic/win32api/datatypes/) might help. It says use Long for DWORD (as you are doing).

Comment: You need to pass the parameters when you actually call the function in VB6. Something like `openComm = MTK_ConnectDevice(0, 1)`.

You will need to pass correct values, not `0` and `1`!

Comment: The `Declare Function` in VB6 is like a function prototype. It tells the VB6 compiler what arguments the function takes.

Comment: You need to turn the comments into an answer rather than editing your question. Then a day later you mark your answer as the answer to your question.

Comment: @user14797724 Hi, may i know how to turn the comments into an answer, due i only able to saw bookmark and recent activity and i cant find the question answered button.Thank you

Comment: You need to distill comments that helped you into an answer. Just by answering your question.